RateLimitError for OpenAI API key despite not having used it
I'm trying to make a chatbot using the OpenAI API Key. Here's the code:
import openai

openai.api_key = "[key]"
response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
  model="gpt-3.5-turbo", 
  messages=[
        {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."},
        {"role": "user", "content": "Tell me a joke."}
    ]
)

print(response.choices[0].message.content)

I'm getting a RateLimitError saying that I've exceeded my current usage limit and I'll need to upgrade my plan, even though I've never used it before. I get the error even before I get a chance to send a message. This is the error:
/usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/[]/Coding/chatgpt_api_test.py
[] ~ % /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/[]/Coding/chatgpt_api_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/[]/Coding/chatgpt_api_test.py", line 4, in <module>
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/openai/api_resources/chat_completion.py", line 25, in create
    return super().create(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/openai/api_resources/abstract/engine_api_resource.py", line 153, in create
    response, _, api_key = requestor.request(
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/openai/api_requestor.py", line 298, in request
    resp, got_stream = self._interpret_response(result, stream)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/openai/api_requestor.py", line 700, in _interpret_response
    self._interpret_response_line(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/openai/api_requestor.py", line 765, in _interpret_response_line
    raise self.handle_error_response(
openai.error.RateLimitError: You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details. For more information on this error, read the docs: https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/error-codes/api-errors.


I checked my OpenAI billing credentials and I still have the default, unused amount of tokens available - I've also tried getting a new API key but still run into the same error. Is this a problem with my code/usage, or should I fix something in my OpenAI account settings (or is it something else)

I see you are using an old version of openai, so I assume that might only be the case in your specific version.
That code works for me with openai==0.28.0
Run pip install openai=0.28.0 and try again.
